# ImageView's image isn't adjusted with LinearLayout's height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

First time asking a question, so please be gentle. :)

I'm trying to create a nested layout of `ImageView`s inside a `LinearLayout`. The parent `LinearLayout` needs to match the root view's width but have it's height determined by the 2 `ImageView` components it holds.

The 2 `ImageView` components need to be equally weighted for width (i.e. 50%) within the `LinearLayout` parent and have retain their proportional height.

However, whilst the width of the `ImageView`s are calculating correctly and the height of the image itself is correct, the height of the parent `LinearLayout` is not.

Below is the XML code I am using, apologies but I do not currently have enough reputation points to post images, which could make this difficult.

**XML Code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/container_dropshadow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is what I am getting**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, apologies for any failing in etiquette,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following line for each `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

For more info about the *xml* attribute see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)